# What properties do have odd quadratic parabola and even cubic parabola? Were they ever described?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, conic-sections, special-functions, cubics

Here is a normal quadratic parabola:

$f_{even}=\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}6$

Here is an odd parabola:

$f_{odd}=  \text{Li}_2\left(e^x\right)+ x \log \left(1-e^x\right)-\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\right)$

The difference between them goes to zero as $x\to\infty$

[image]

Here is a normal cubic parabola (odd):

$f_{odd}=\frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{\pi ^2 x}{6}$

Here is an even cubic parabola:

$f_{even}=2 \text{Li}_3\left(e^x\right)-x \text{Li}_2\left(e^x\right)-\left(\frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{\pi ^2 x}{6}\right)$

They approach each other at infinity:

[image]

So, what properties can have those counterparts of normal polynomials but with the opposite parity? Are there properties, common with polynomials or conic sections?

Comment: How are you characterizing these alternative parabolas? (I'll ignore that "cubic parabola" is a bit of a misnomer since the term is [not unknown](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicalParabola.html).) Are you interested in curves that are simply *asymptotic* to the "polynomial parabolas", or is there something special about the ones involving the logs and polylogs?

Comment: @Blue I think it is impossible to build such curves (asymptotically similar to polynomials but with inverted parity) in any other way. This construction is special, yes https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396076/asymptotically-similar-functions-with-opposite-parity-were-they-considered-are